# How To fix these Warning Overfull \hbox (202.24913pt too wide)?

Tags: warnings

I have this warning a lot on file: 
Overfull \hbox (202.24913pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 7--8
Here is an example

```
   \documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,arrows.meta}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}

     \item The distributor sends a transaction to the blockchain containing 
   ($\sigma_{agg} || 
   PK_{V_{1}},\ldots,PK_{V_{m}}||C^{M_\theta}_{PK_{V_1}},\ldots, 
    C^{M_\theta}_{PK_{V_m}}|| k_{1},\ldots, k_{m})$ where $m$ is the number 
  of vehicles that received the update.


  \end{enumerate}
  \end{document}
```

Comment: Is your actual document a `standalone` or did you use it only for  the MWE?

Comment: Can you go back to your previous questions and look if the answers solve your problems and accept them, if they do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possible solutions assuming you use `article` and not `standalone`. The first one writes the math expression as a non numbered equation and the second inserts a manual break in math.

I prefer the first one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,arrows.meta}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}

     \item The distributor sends a transaction to the blockchain containing 
  \[ (\sigma_{agg} || 
   PK_{V_{1}},\ldots,PK_{V_{m}}||C^{M_\theta}_{PK_{V_1}},\ldots, 
    C^{M_\theta}_{PK_{V_m}}|| k_{1},\ldots, k_{m}) \] where $m$ is the number 
  of vehicles that received the update.

     \item The distributor sends a transaction to the blockchain containing 
  $(\sigma_{agg} ||$ $PK_{V_{1}},\ldots,PK_{V_{m}}||C^{M_\theta}_{PK_{V_1}},\ldots, 
    C^{M_\theta}_{PK_{V_m}}|| k_{1},\ldots, k_{m})$ where $m$ is the number 
  of vehicles that received the update.

  \end{enumerate}
  \end{document}
```

[image]